Design Pattern for Raising Exception on an Attempt to Access a Removed API Element
I'd like to know what the best design pattern is for giving users a specific error message when they attempt to access an API element that I've removed.
Previous Release
For example, I have a library with a deprecated method A.foo.
import warnings

class A:
    def foo(self):
        warnings.warn(f"`A.foo` is deprecated, use `A.bar` instead.", DeprecationWarning)
        # Do stuff

    def bar(self):
        # Do stuff

New Release
In a new release, I'm removing A.foo, but I still want to keep a specific error message similar to that from the previous release to continue to help users refactor their code. One option is to keep foo, remove all its functionality, and raise an error with my message. I don't see any exception type that seems specifically intended for this purpose, so perhaps a NameError would be the best choice?
class A:
    def foo(self):
        raise NameError(f"`A.foo` was removed, use `A.bar` instead.")

    def bar(self):
        # Do stuff

The absence of a specific Exception subclass for this common occurrence leaves me wondering if there is a completely different design pattern that would be better to use. Any input is appreciated.

For warnings there is a pep with a deprecation decorator comming up for 3.13: https://peps.python.org/pep-0702/ IMHO the most pythonic way to do it after removing the function is just to not specially handle the call of this function and let python throw the default exception itself.

@user_na My main concern with the default AttributeError exception is that it's not specific and leaves it difficult for users to find how to refactor their code. In my case, I'm working on a small, quickly evolving library where there isn't much time between a function being deprecated and it being removed. I want to users to still have guidance even if they missed refactoring within the window where the function was deprecated.
